# SVN combine projects + arrange by commit date

Tags: svn, repository, svn-repository

So currently our projects are in their own repos, but we want to change it so that the projects are under one repo. So currently we have:

- repoA

  - trunk
  - branchs
- repoB

  - trunk
  - branchs
- ...

and we are going for:

- trunk

  - repoA
  - repoB
  - ...
- branchs

  - repoA
  - repoB
  - ...

The real problem I'm having is that we would like to have the commits in new repo to be in date order.

Do I have to make the new repo and load all projects into that so that they just get new rev numbers. Then somehow move the commits to second new repo with date ordering?

So any help how I can achieve ordering of the commits to combined repo would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Probably, yes. This ought to be possible by svndump-ing both repositories; you'll then have to modify the paths in each dump and then likely zip them together in commit order, making sure to update any metadata references to commit numbers that you're changing such as svn:merge-info, then svn load into a new repository. (And it's 'branches' with an 'e'.)

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here.  First, to merge the dump files so that the revs are in date order, you can use [this tool](http://svn.borg.ch/svndumptool/) (it's worked for me).  However, as noted in a comment above, you could run into problems due to the changing rev numbers (e.g. I don't know if that tool deals with svn:merginfo properties).

Secondly, doing the rearrangement of pathnames is trickier.  You'll need to change the pathnames in the dump files.  I've used [this perl module](http://search.cpan.org/~mscharrer/SVN-Dumpfilter-0.21/lib/SVN/Dumpfilter.pm) to do this sort of thing.

But a simpler answer would be to just load the dump files into a fresh repository like so:

```
svnadmin dump -q repoA | svnadmin load --parent-dir repoA mergedrepos
svnadmin dump -q repoB | svnadmin load --parent-dir repoB mergedrepos
```

Yes, the revision dates will be out of order, but I have done this a number of times and it hasn't caused me or my users any problems thus far.  When you do queries using svn log of files within repoA or repoB the dates will be in order, it's only if files get moved between the two, or if you run svn log on the entire repository, that the order issue would show up.

Once you have the two repositories loaded, you could move things around into the structure you want, e.g.

```
svn mv file:///svn/mergedrepos/repoA/trunk file:///svn/mergedrepos/trunk/repoA
```

Note, you may have to create directories before the loads and the mv commands, but that is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

> (And it's 'branches' with an 'e'.)

Yes, I know it's branches and thats how it is in our svn as well. :)

trent: thanks for the info, I had figured out it would work like you told me. So I wrote a script that combines the projects to one.

I know the history will look funny only when looking at trunk, but the kind wish was that the commits would be sorted by date. I haven't really figured out how would I be able to sort the commits by date. So does anyone have an idea how I could sort out the commits to be in date order?

edit: Look like [mergerepo script](http://www.cri.ensmp.fr/~coelho/svn-merge-repos.html) will let me do the sorting and merging quite easily

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same problem for a time. The [SVN merge script](http://www.cri.ensmp.fr/~coelho/svn-merge-repos.html) mentioned in another answer explicitly says that it is discouraged for merging large and independent repositories (which happens to be my case).

The solution I found was to split submissions from both repositories and to sort them by date, then load each individual submission separately into the new repository.

- Create dump files (they have `.out` extension to avoid conflicts with the sorting tool used later).

  ```
  svnadmin dump \path\to\repoA > repoA.out
  svnadmin dump \path\to\repoB > repoB.out
  ```
- Split dump files into individual revisions. To do so I've used [svndumptool](http://svn.borg.ch/svndumptool/) (mentioned in the webpage of the aforementioned merge script). Syntax is `svndumptool split src_file start_rev end_rev tgt_file`. Unfortunately it extracts revisions one range at a time. To overcome this you can use the following Batch script:

  ```
  REM split.bat
  for /L %%I in (%2, 1, %3) do (
    svndumptool split %1 %%I %%I %4.%%I.dump
  )
  ```

  Syntax would be then:

  ```
  split repoA.out 0 1000 repoA
  split repoB.out 0 2000 repoB
  ```

  It will generate a set of `.dump` files.
- I've used the program lined out at the end of the answer (I've called it `svn_merge_by_date`) to sort revisions by date and load them into the new repository accordingly: `svn_merge_by_date new_repo_name`.

In my case, repositories were completely independent to each other, so no directories had the same name. If it is your case it would be safer to to keep track of the original repository and load into a different directory. Each dump file contains the UUID of the repository so you can use them.

With this you keep both history AND revisions are kept sorted by time too.

---

Code for `svn_merge_by_date`. It is in C++ and requires Boost to compile it. Basically it will scan for all `.dump` files in current directory, sort them by revision date and load into the new repository (the first command line parameter).

```
// DISCLAIMER: This code has been developed to solve a very specific
//             and one-time problem and it is given AS IS.

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

void get_all(const fs::path& root, const std::string& ext, std::vector<fs::path>& ret)
{
  if (!fs::exists(root) || !fs::is_directory(root)) return;

  fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(root), endit;
  while (it != endit) {
    if (fs::is_regular_file(*it) && it->path().extension() == ext) ret.push_back(it->path().filename());
    ++it;
  }
}

std::string get_date(const fs::path& filename)
{
  std::ifstream f(filename.string());
  if (f) {
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(f, line)) {
      if (line == "svn:date") { // date is two lines below
        std::getline(f, line);
        std::getline(f, line);
        return line;
      }
    }
  }

  return "";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc < 2) return 0;

  const std::string svn_path(argv[1]);

  std::vector<fs::path> filenames;
  get_all(".", ".dump", filenames);

  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, fs::path>> sorted_files;
  for (auto it = filenames.begin(); it != filenames.end(); ++it) {
    const auto date = get_date(*it);
    if (!date.empty()) {
      sorted_files.push_back(std::make_pair(date, *it));
    }
  }
  std::sort(sorted_files.begin(), sorted_files.end());

  for (auto it = sorted_files.begin(); it != sorted_files.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << it->first << " -> " << it->second << std::endl;
    const auto cmd = std::string("svnadmin load ") + svn_path + " < " + it->second.string();
    system(cmd.c_str());
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

PS: if your repository is large, let's say several gigabytes, I've found a good option to split dump files into smaller files (containing just a few hundred of revisions each one) before proceeding to split them into individual revisions.